# Include rows in ROW_NUMBER() where greater than 1 including the first value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, row-number

I need to find users that have the same name, surname and date of birth. I have to include each one's client ID as well so I can't use `COUNT(*)` with group by. I am using `ROW_NUMBER()` partitioned by those three columns in a CTE. But I need to include all the multiple values including `where rownumber = 1`.

This is what I have now:

```
;WITH 
Rownumbers AS
(
    SELECT 
        [Client code]
        ,Name
        ,Surname
        ,[Date of Birth]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER
            (PARTITION BY 
                name
                ,surname
                ,[DATE of birth]
            ORDER BY 
                [client code]
            )AS [Row Number]

    FROM 
        kyc_details
)

SELECT 
,[client code]
,Name
,Surname
,[DATE of birth]
,[Row Number] 
FROM 
[Rownumbers]
WHERE
[Row Number] > 1
```

The issue here is, I need to include the `rownumber = 1`. In essence I need to select all the columns with duplicate values but the client code will be unique.

Comment: Did you consider using join? join the table to it self and where id <> id and all the other values equal . It will give you only the duplicates.

Comment: "Find users that has the same name, surname and date of birth" is not clear. Do you mean, find users that have the same name, surname and date of birth as another user? Or, find users that have the same name, surname or date of birth as another user?

Comment: say you get 2 `client_code` for same client `name`,`surname` and `dob`. How do you want to proceed in that case? Please add some sample data and expected output .

Answer (score 5):

Here is the answer (I used a count over partitioned by):

```
;WITH 
rownumbers AS 
(
    SELECT 
        [Client code],name, surname, [date of birth]
        ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY  kd.name, kd.Surname,[DATE of birth]) AS total
FROM 
    kyc_details AS kd 

   )

SELECT 
,[client code]
,Name
,Surname
,[DATE of birth]
,total  
FROM 
rownumbers
WHERE 
total > 1   
ORDER BY 
Name
,surname
```

Comment: Please accept this answer so others know the question is solved.